# Single sided buffer produces no result in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-processing

I've mostly used ArcGIS Desktop but am trying to use QGIS to do a one sided buffer since I only have a basic license.

I have a coastline and want to do an offshore buffer polygon. The line file is projected to a state plane system consistent with my desired buffer units.

I've opened "Single sided buffers (and offset lines) for lines" put in my coastline shapefile line file, selected single side buffer, selected geometry, input buffer distance, selected right, and specified an output shapefile. When I Run this nothing happens...

What am I missing?

Comment: Does a regular buffer with the same buffer size work correctly?

Comment: Yes, a regular buffer with the same size seems to work just fine.

Comment: @JohnSmithy - Which QGIS version and platform are you using?

Comment: Just in case your line layer came from ArcGIS Geodatabase, changing Geometry column name (default = `geometry` to something like `SHAPE`) may work...

Comment: I'm using 2.18.16. Changing to shape didn't work either. I found a work around in Arc so I'm no longer waiting on this but may be helpful if others have the same issue. Thanks all.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that it was something along the lines of what @Kazuhito suggested so I would recommend others to start there.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the "Open output file after running algorithm".

When you have it unchecked, the shape will be created and saved on the route you choose but it will not be added to the layers panel.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I've tried with the 'open output file after running algorithm" check and unchecked without a result.